# Environment specific service endpoint in angular2 with angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am uning angular-cli for my angular2 project.

I am calling backend ajax services through my angular2 service.

I have different services end point (URL) for different task.
I want to make those services environment sensetive.

Suppose I have two service

1. Customer Service : `https://localhost:8080/customers`
2. Product Service : `https://localhost:8080/products`

Since `localhost` is avaliable in my development environment. It is working

Now suppose `x.x.x.x` is my production web service host ip address.

So for production environment the service URL will be https://x.x.x.x:8080/customers

Please help me how to achive this.

I found there is a block in angular-cli.json file as

```
"environments": {
    "source": "environments/environment.ts",
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

But I did now found that environments directory.

How to create that and manage environment specific end points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command **ng new PROJECT_NAME** was supposed to create both files:

- src/environments/environment.prod.ts
- src/environments/environment.ts

I believe you can create it manually. Here is the generated code:

```
// The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.
// The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do
// `ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.
// The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `angular-cli.json`.

export const environment = {
  production: false
};
```

You can add the configuration you need in both files for the respectful environment:

```
// src/environments/environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

...

```
// src/environments/environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'https://x.x.x.x'
};
```

To use the configuration just:

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

//...

let url = `${environment.apiUrl}/customers`;
```

Just make sure you are importing **'../environments/environment'** and NOT '../environments/environment.prod'.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Right now I am trying setup a mock environment without using original service end point but some mock JSON file as endpoint. But I am facing some issues to POST to a JSON file URL. Here is my SO question. Please take a look if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634007/angular2-setup-mock-environment-using-json-file

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your variables in environment files like that:
`process.env.apiHost = "http://myhostfordevorprod"`
You should put that before export in your environment file: 
`export const environment = {
  production: false, //or true
};`
and access it in your component like this: 
`my_var = process.env.apiHost`
Then you run `ng build --environment=production` or `ng build --environment=development` to choose which environment file to load. Instead build you could also run `ng serve --environment=development`