# How to get value of --env variable in Angular 5 server.ts?

Tags: angular, angular5, devops, angular-universal, ng-build

Currently i have three environments and I am trying to get `--env=prod` value in my `server.ts` which in this case is `prod`
I am getting the right environment object in my angular app but issues getting it in my `server.ts` file which is necessary for achieving ssr
i am setting the environment using the attribute `--env=prod` or `--env=dev` and importing in my `server.ts` like 
`import { environment } from'./src/environments/environment';`

this is what my environment object in `.angular-cli.json` looks like for both angular and server platform

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "test": "environments/environment.test.ts"
  }
```

and i do have all the files in the mentioned path

Comment: Can you show your angular-cli settings where environment names and environmentSource is defined, also post your environment.prod.ts

Comment: `{
"environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
        "stage": "environments/environment.stage.ts"
      }
}`
this is what it looks like and i do have all these files in mentioned paths
I am getting the correct environment on the client (i.e angular app) but problem getting environment object in server.ts which is used for ssr purposes

Comment: if you're using docker i'd recommend an approach using gulp or something to generate a config file just when express starts up. https://medium.com/@kudresov/a-better-way-to-inject-environmental-variables-in-angular-d3b2d01a3c5e

Answer (score 3):

It amazes me how difficult it is for people to understand this issue. Yelling the same thing in bold all-caps is just silly.

Simplified:

```
environment.ts = { magicKey: "default" }

environment.prod.ts = { magicKey: "46df465d4f64fd654f6fe4d64f" }
```

---- after building with "--configuration=prod" ----

In app.component:

```
import { environment } from "environments/environment";
console.log(environment.magicKey); // == "46df465d4f64fd654f6fe4d64f"
```

In server.ts:

```
import { environment } from "environments/environment";
```

NOTE: This gives build error "Can't resolve 'environments/environment' in server.ts". 
Other threads suggest using the correct relative path, but now it seems that we just get the default file i.e. "fileReplacements" is not being respected/used:

```
import { environment } from "./src/environments/environment";
console.log(environment.magicKey); // == "default"
```

As far as i can tell... it should work. I have also verified that "fileReplacements" also exists for "server" in angular.json... no go though. It just doesn't seem to want to replace the file.

I assume this is because the "replace" just doesn't happen for server.ts. It's "outside" of the app and thus the fancy logic doesn't happen? Or maybe that the import (being different) is overriding it?

My workaround, is simply to import all environments in server.ts and the select the correct one based on an environment (process.env) variable that i set on each machine.

If anyone has some insights, then I'm sure I'm not the only one interested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
// use path to your environments file.

private apiEndPoint: string;

constructor() {
    this.apiEndPoint = environment.apiUrl;
}
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423716/environment-specific-service-endpoint-in-angular2-with-angular-cli) for more info

Comment: i'm using angular universal this is not a path issue i'm facing its more about i need the environment object in my server.ts

Comment: you can access environment object using the above way. Did you try?

Comment: yes i did try but i'm only getting default dev environment

Answer (score 0):

Angular handles the environment variable at build time.

When you write

```
import { environment } from 'environment';
```

Angular takes the environment you decide when you run your build command.

This means that even though you imported the dev environment (the default one), if you write

```
ng build --prod
```

Your production environment will be taken.

And by the way, if you don't have the exact same values in your environment files, you will have a compilation error. So you might as well copy and paste your variables from one environment to another.

Comment: `Cannot find module 'environment'.` 
i'm using angular universal this is not a path issue i'm facing its more about i need the environment object in my server.ts

Comment: I'm not talking about any path, and I didn't ask you to copy and paste the lines of code, I made an example to explain to you. Let me make it simpler to you : **the command `ng build` decides what environment will be used**, and **all of your environment files must have the exact same properties**.

Comment: Yes i do have the exact same properties in all the environment files but i don't understand why i'm only getting dev environment file

Comment: **THE COMMAND `ng build` DECIDES WHAT ENVIRONMENT WILL BE USED**. I really can't make it clearer.

Comment: bro you need to calm down first i know which command do what i did try it with `ng build --prod --env=dev` and `ng build --prod --env=prod` but it didn't work only giving me development environment file thats what i've beens saying

Comment: Because the syntax is `--env prod`, and you didn't give us your CLI file so we don't know if you set up your environments correctly. I'm very calm, you're just not getting my point so I emphasize them.

Comment: my friend you got to see [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/f32089967416ed08d06d08be34afdb45e4a54969/docs/documentation/1-x/build.md#build-targets-and-environment-files) they says `--env=prod` not `--env prod` plus this is not the issue i'm facing i just need the selected environment object in my server.ts or via `process.env` object

Answer (score 0):

Update `angular-cli` to latest, if you already haven't

leave `environments/environment.ts` and don't use it for `dev`, instead create one `environment.dev.ts`

Add one `environmentSource`, if you doesn't have one.

```
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "test": "environments/environment.test.ts"
  }
```

Comment: so what will i import on `server.ts` dev or prod and how do i do it without knowing which environment to run when ?